# ReBindData to controls in asp

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

yesterday i started my adventure with asp.net and i have a little problem.

i have a function that gets data from MySQL DB and binds to 2 controls - gridview and drop down list

```
protected void BindData(MySqlConnection c)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pracownicy", c);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);            
        grid.DataSource = ds;
        grid.DataBind();
        usersid.DataSource = ds;
        usersid.DataBind();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

first time it is called in Page_Load function and it's working fine.

I have a button, after click it add some data to DB - working fine.

now i'm trying to add (after insert data to MySQL DB) clear the grid control with

```
grid.DataSource = "";
grid.DataBind();
```

It removes all table, but when i try to call BindData function once more in button click event after insert data, nothing happens at all (even data is not added to database then).

No errors, No warnings. Just nothing.

There is adding func and click event

```
protected void AddData(MySqlConnection c, string _imie, string _nazwisko, string _mail, string _dzial)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO pracownicy(imie,nazwisko,mail,dzial) VALUES ('" + _imie + "', '" + _nazwisko + "', '" + _mail + "', '" + _dzial + "'); ";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,c);
        cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }


    protected void wykonaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, MySqlConnection c)
    {
        string selected_str = (akcja.SelectedValue != "Wybierz") ? akcja.SelectedValue : "0";
        string _m = (mail.Text != "") ? mail.Text : "";
        int selected = Int32.Parse(selected_str);

        grid.DataSource = "";
        grid.DataBind();

        switch (selected)
        {
            case 1:
                if (imie.Text != "" && nazwisko.Text != "" && dzial.Text != "")
                {
                    AddData(c, imie.Text, nazwisko.Text, _m, dzial.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Error Alert
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                //modify
                break;
            case 3:
                //delete
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Add event click to a button

```
wykonaj.Click += new EventHandler((s, b) => wykonaj_Click(s, b, connection));
```

How can i make this ?

Comment: If you're just now learning, why did you choose Web Forms to start with, of all things? Why didn't you choose a modern and actively developed framework?

Comment: A data source is often a collection, you shouldn't convert to an empty string you would want it to be an empty collection.  That way it still holds your object data to persist, otherwise you just cause more state issues for yourself.

Comment: Could you submit a more complete code sample, web forms relies heavily on state and order.  So for us to help you we need to see more code, so we can follow all those changes.

Comment: @Greg i put code in the next post

Comment: @Jarzyn I'll take a look later, let me catch up with my Monday work then I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code present you appear to be in the mindset of universal code, one method to control multiple data binding.  However, the approach could be improved to achieve that flexibility.  Since I'm partial to expressive code, I would separate but do the following.

```
public interface IDataBinder<TModel> : IDisposable
{
     IEnumerable<TModel> RetrieveAll();
}
```

Now that our contract has been defined, we can implement.

```
public class SampleContext : IDataBinder<SampleModel>
{
     private const string getAllSamplesQuery = "SELECT ...";
     private IDbConnection dbConnection;

     public SampleContext() => dbConnection = new SqlConnection("...");

     public IEnumerable<SampleModel> RetrieveAll() => dbConnection.Query<SampleModel>(getAllSamplesQuery);
}
```

*For brevity I didn't write the query, connection string, utilize a notion of Dapper, and did not implement the dispose functionality*.

Now for a nice clean call, I implement a factory.

```
public interface ISampleFactory
{
     IDataBinder<SampleModel> Create();
}

public class SampleFactory
{
     public IDataBinder<SampleModel> Create() => new SampleContext();
}
```

This will provide us with a nice syntax.

```
using(var context = new SampleFactory().Create())
     return context.RetrieveAll();
```

So the above simply cleans up and creates some structure for your data calls.  But now to the root of your problem, web forms and the glorious notion of a state driven framework.

So if you want your grid and dropdown to constantly update when the page refreshes, what you need would be to not choose `PageIsPostback()` or `!PageIsPostback()`.  However, an event will fire after page load every time.  So the enumerable collection may be empty before you mutate within your event.

But by creating a little structure and ensuring the events fire in correct order should rectify.  But with my syntax above you could do:

```
using(var context = new SampleFactory().Create())
     grdSample.DataSource = context.RetrieveAll();

grdSample.DataBind();
```

No fancy method that constantly alters, a devoted expressive call to the proper object you intend to populate.  Since you use a model, you can share between multiple controls.

Hope this at least helps you.

Answer (score 0):

@Greg

this is complete code-behind file. there was some changes, so.

look at the Page_Load method. BindData is a function that binds data to my controls. It's working like that but if i put this behind if(isPostBack) block code nothing happens at all.
in Data_Update im executing query with insert/update/delete in my DB so i wanted to bind data after modify BD not before but as i told nothing happens. No errors, no warnings, data doesnt bind and even query is not executed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = connect();
        BindData(connection);
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            data_Update(connection);
        }
    }

    protected MySqlConnection connect()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=marcin;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=test;password=pass");
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }

    protected void BindData(MySqlConnection c)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pracownicy", c);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);            
        grid.DataSource = ds;
        grid.DataBind();
        usersid.DataSource = ds;
        usersid.DataBind();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

    protected void ExecuteQuery(string query, MySqlConnection c)    
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, c);
        cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

    protected void data_Update(MySqlConnection conn)
    {

        string query = "";
        string selected_str = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$akcja"];
        string _id = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$usersid"];
        string _imie = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$imie"];
        string _nazwisko = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$nazwisko"];
        string _dzial = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$dzial"];
        string _mail = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$mail"];

        selected_str = (selected_str != "Wybierz") ? selected_str : "0";

        int selected = Int32.Parse(selected_str);

        switch (selected)
        {
            case 1:
                if ( _imie != "" && _nazwisko != "" && _dzial != "")
                {
                    query = "INSERT INTO pracownicy(imie,nazwisko,mail,dzial) VALUES ('" + _imie + "', '" + _nazwisko + "', '" + _mail + "', '" + _dzial + "'); ";

                }
                else
                {
                    CreateAlertError("Sprawdź czy zostały podane wymagane dane: imie, nazwisko, dział");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if ( _imie != "" && _nazwisko != "" && _dzial != "")
                {
                    query = "UPDATE pracownicy SET imie='" + _imie + "', nazwisko='" + _nazwisko + "', mail='" + _mail + "', dzial='" + _dzial + "' WHERE id=" + _id + ";";

                }
                else
                {
                    CreateAlertError("Sprawdź czy zostały podane wymagane dane: imie, nazwisko, dział");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                query = "DELETE FROM pracownicy WHERE id=" + _id +";";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if(query != "")
            ExecuteQuery(query, conn);
    }

    protected void CreateAlertError(string message)
    {
        HyperLink close = new HyperLink();
        Panel alert = new Panel();
        close.CssClass = "close";
        close.Text = "&times;";
        close.Attributes["data-dismiss"] = "alert";
        close.Attributes["aria-label"] = "close";
        close.NavigateUrl = "#";
        alert.CssClass = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in";
        alert.Controls.Add(close);
        alert.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(message));
        info_containter.Controls.Clear();
        info_containter.Controls.Add(alert);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Whoa, that code.  Your approach is not manageable.  You should simplify, a lot of areas could fail making this difficult to diagnose.  I'll have to write some code at lunch, a example of what I mean.

Comment: @Greg is that a real mess ? ;P